# Calling functions between components in Coldfusion

Tags: function, coldfusion, cfc, cfml

Say I have a project, I have several CFC's in that project. For the sake of the example, I have a debugging function `general.cfc` and I want to use that function in `mandrill.cfc` without having to copy and paste the code into the latter cfc. I've googled this until I can google no more and I know I need to post it here.

Anyone care to take me to school?

Comment: Not sure why there are close votes. It's not a very complicated question, but it's still a question, and valid in the context of ColdFusion (I wonder if the vote-to-close people are even CF users?)

Comment: *I wonder if the vote-to-close people are even CF users?* Doubtful, because neither of the reasons apply. The question is clear and it is not too broad. Voted to leave open.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I would do it

```
<cfset var objGeneral = createObject("component","general")>
```

Then if you have a function in `general.cfc` called `getName()` you can call it by saying `objGeneral.getName()`

Comment: Remember to scope! `<cfset var objGeneral = createObject("component","general")>` or `<cfset variables.objGeneral = createObject("component","general")>` or `<cfset local.objGeneral = createObject("component","general")>`

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that objGeneral can be set in the pseudo-constructor (outside any function definitions but inside `<cfcomponent>`) and used throughout the CFC.

Comment: The original function was about using a function. Wouldn't `<cfinvoke>` be better?

Comment: @JamesMohler no, there aren't any real reasons to use `<cfinvoke>`. Creating the object has basically zero cost.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the notion of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and you should specifically look at how [ColdSpring](http://www.coldspringframework.org/) implements it in the context of ColdFusion (or [DI/1](http://di1.riaforge.org/)).

Basically you have an init() argument in `Mandrill` which would take a `General` object, and then you set the `General` object into the variables scope of the `Mandrill` object, using its methods via `variables.general`.

That said, this works best on singleton objects. If you need to do this sort of thing on a transient object, I'd just instantiate the `General` object as needed within your `Mandrill` code (ie: now Matt Busche is suggesting).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to have `mandrill.cfc` [extend](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=buildingComponents_30.html) the `general.cfc` component:

```
<cfcomponent extends="general" name="mandrill" ...>
```

See also [`CreateObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-697b.html)

Comment: Disagree. From the description of the components, a Mandrill is *not* a General, so it's not a subclass of it.

Comment: Matt Busche has a better idea.